# correlation coefficient proof

Tags: probability, random-variables, correlation

For two random variables $X$ and $Y$

We know that $\rho = \frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y} = 1 $  if and only if $X = cY$ for some constant $c$.

If $X = cY$, then $\rho = 1$ is easy to prove.

If $\rho = 1$, then how do we prove $X = cY$ for some constant c?

EDIT: Can we even prove that?

If $\rho = 1$, then at best we can prove that $X - E[X] = c (Y - E[Y])$ for some constant c?

Comment: From $\rho=1$ you can only say $Y=a+bX$ with probability $1$ for some $a$ and $b>0$. Does not necessarily mean that $X$ is just a scalar multiple of $Y$ or vice versa.

Comment: A similar case: If $X$ is independent from $Y$ then $Cov(X,Y)=0$. But $Cov(X,Y)=0$ does not necessarily mean that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.